# Laravel How could i query relations on eager loading and just showed query the items

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problem with querying relations, i would like to query data inside the relations, but only showing the property item that has the relations data.

```
$property = Property::with([
        'member' => function ($query) use ($value) {
           return $query->select('ID', 'NAMA')->where('NAMA', $value);
    },
        'province:ID,NAMA',
        'city:ID,NAMA',
        'district:ID,NAMA',
        'village:ID,NAMA',
        'unitcertificate',
        'facility.facility',
        'furniture.furniture',
        'accessibility.accessibility',
        'nearest_area',
        'file'])->take(5)->get();

public function member()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Member::class, 'ID', 'id_agen');
}
```

For example i have a table **property**, but i'm querying inside the relations table of **member**, i would like to have only the data that have the query on relations only, not all the property.But I got this instead

```
  {
      "id_property": "PR10130420221200002",
      "property_name": "Elroy Erasmo Flower",
      "property_price": 1000000000000,
      "subsidi_type": 2,
      "property_type": "2",
      "unit_type": 3,
      "id_agen": 1,
      "postal_code": 53177,
      "sale_status_id": 1,
      "latitude": -6.97003693,
      "longitude": 110.46976524,
      "created_at": "2022-12-04T07:24:41.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-12-04T07:24:41.000000Z",
      "member": null,
    },
    {
        "id_property": "PR10130420221200004",
        "property_name": "Becki Nancie CV",
        "property_price": 2000000000000,
        "subsidi_type": 1,
        "property_type": "2",
        "unit_type": 2,
        "url_video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYIuPDJK7oc",
        "id_agen": 55,
        "postal_code": 53177,
        "sale_status_id": 1,
        "latitude": -6.48328224,
        "longitude": 106.98369993,
        "created_at": "2022-12-04T07:24:41.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-12-04T07:24:41.000000Z",
        "member": {
            "ID": 55,
            "NAMA": "Sella Augusta Bulan"
        },
    },
    {
        "id_property": "PR10130420221200004",
        "property_name": "Becki Nancie CV",
        "property_price": 2000000000000,
        "subsidi_type": 1,
        "property_type": "2",
        "unit_type": 2,,
        "id_agen": 55,
      "postal_code": 53177,
        "sale_status_id": 1,
        "latitude": -6.48328224,
        "longitude": 106.98369993,
        "created_at": "2022-12-04T07:24:41.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-12-04T07:24:41.000000Z",
        "member": {
            "ID": 55,
            "NAMA": "Sella Augusta Bulan"
        },
    }
```

i still could get the property data with no querying result of member, what it  is mean the **member: null**, i hope i could get it like this

```
    {
        "id_property": "PR10130420221200004",
        "property_name": "Becki Nancie CV",
        "property_price": 2000000000000,
        "subsidi_type": 1,
        "property_type": "2",
        "unit_type": 2,
        "url_video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYIuPDJK7oc",
        "id_agen": 55,
        "postal_code": 53177,
        "sale_status_id": 1,
        "latitude": -6.48328224,
        "longitude": 106.98369993,
        "created_at": "2022-12-04T07:24:41.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-12-04T07:24:41.000000Z",
        "member": {
            "ID": 55,
            "NAMA": "Sella Augusta Bulan"
        },
    },
    {
        "id_property": "PR10130420221200004",
        "property_name": "Becki Nancie CV",
        "property_price": 2000000000000,
        "subsidi_type": 1,
        "property_type": "2",
        "unit_type": 2,,
        "id_agen": 55,
        "postal_code": 53177,
        "sale_status_id": 1,
        "latitude": -6.48328224,
        "longitude": 106.98369993,
        "created_at": "2022-12-04T07:24:41.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-12-04T07:24:41.000000Z",
        "member": {
            "ID": 55,
            "NAMA": "Sella Augusta Bulan"
        },
    }
```

the problem are the table member is on another database

How can i solve that?

Answer (score 0):

try [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
$property = Property::whereHas('member', function ($query) use ($value) {
    return $query->select('ID', 'NAMA')->where('NAMA', $value);
} 
...
...
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but my member table are not in the same database,  how could i do that?